# css- video background for 200VH

Tags: html, css

i want to add a background video  which will be fixed for VH1 and VH2  but it will stop at vh3

so when user open page he see #vh1 and #videoBG as a background video, he keep scrolling and he see #vh2 but  background video is still same(fixed);
as soon he scroll to #vh3  then he see another background image

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="videoBG">
    <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="vh" id="vh1">
    text 1
</div>

<div class="vh" id="vh2">
    text 2
</div>


<div class="vh" id="vh3">
    text 3
</div>
```

> ```
> <style>
> .vh {
>     width: 100vw;
>     height: 100vh;
> }
>
> #vh3 {
>     background: url(IMG/bg1.jpg);
>     background-repeat: no-repeat;
>     background-size: cover;
> }
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make the video on position:fixed; and make it width:100vw; and height:100vh;
you said.  **but it will stop at vh3** its a react i think?

```css
* {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
}
.vh {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
  /*use this on video*/
.video {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:99999;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  /*dont mid this*/
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  /*dont mid this*/
}
```